# Installing driver for asus usb-n13 on win7 without disk

Tags: windows-7, drivers, installation, usb-network-adapter

The problem is - the ZIP files from asus support site contain a bunch of .sys and .inf files(Tried right click->install them, resulted in error), and sometimes an Asus utility as well(tried installing it - no use). Device manager also does not see the driver, even if I point right to driver folder.
OS - Win7 Ultimate

Answer (score 1):

When you use Device Manager, have you tried telling it "Have Disk" and pointing it to that directory where you extracted the ZIP file? Sometimes Windows will not "see" the driver even thought its right there infront of it. Also, not to be offensive, but double check that the driver you downloaded is the one for the device in question.